# Reading data in NFC phone, with NFC Reader

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, nfc-p2p

In my project, i need to send 9 digit number to NFC Reader via my NFC phone. NFC Reader should read the data, and use it in my windows project.

I have Samsung note 3 as NFC phone, and acr122L as NFC Reader.

I've been searching about it, but couldn't find good answer.

How can i send data ? Is there any example, or sample cod?

Comment: Start with the official android guide about nfc https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use HCE (Host Card Emulation) on android device.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html

NFC reader on windows will "see" a card, when you tap your phone.

**UPDATE1**

Regarding windows reader sample, you could have a look at this tutorial:
http://the--semicolon.blogspot.fr/p/this-is-simple-way-to-restart-your.html

And of course at official doc from ACS: http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/144/acr122l-visualvantage-serial-nfc-reader-with-lcd/

Comment: it sounds easy, but i did the hce thing, and downloaded sample. but on computer side, i cant read any tag or card. i can't find read sample, there is a lot of library on internet, every sample using different.

Comment: thank you four your help, i can read the uid of the card, but dont know how to read data inside it. Because of that, im gonna use uid of card in my project